# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have created a Web Application in asp.net 2.0. which is working fine on my Local machine. However when trying to deploy it on sever that has windows 2003 sever, I get the error:

## Server Error in '/' Application.

---

### *Parser Error*

**Description:** An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** The file '/MasterPage.master' does not exist.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="LinkChecker Home " %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
Line 3:
```

**Source File:** /LinkChecker/Default.aspx    **Line**: 1

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Does the master page actually exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is the folder on the web server (IIS presumably) marked as an ASP.NET application? If not, ~/ will point to the next application up, or the site root.

It should have a cog icon in the IIS/MMC snap-in. Also ensure that it is running the right version of ASP.NET (v2.blah usually).

In the IIS/MMC view, find the folder that is your project; right-click; Properties.
Check it has an Application Name; if it doesn't, click Create. You might also want to tweak the app-pool if you want it to run in a different identity than default. Also check the ASP.NET tab - for example, it might be 2.0.50727.

Comment: that is probably exactly what it is.

Comment: I second this - you need to be running at least .Net 2.0 for master pages to work.  Check what app pool you are using - if you have a mix of .net 1.1 and 2.0 apps, you cannot mix framework versions in the one pool.

Answer (score 0):

There are other possible issues that could result in the error message stated above, like permission problems on the server for instance.

Look [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/972609/1228020.aspx) for a thread in which this topic is also discussed.